# How to flag emails as public vs internal?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have Excel VBA code to send emails to a list of emails/names. This works.

The company implemented security measures and we have to mark all outbound emails as public.

Is there was a way to flag emails as public vs internal?

```
Sub Mass_Email_Template()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, company As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = 5
    'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extracts the first name only
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        company = Cells(i, 5).Value
        
        'can replace parts of email here
        body = Replace(body, "[first name]", name)
        body = Replace(body, "[company]", company)
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = email
             .cc = copy
             .subject = subject
             .body = body
             '.Attachments.Add ("") 'We can add attachments here
             .display
             '.Send 'if this is active, it will send email
        End With
        
        'resets the text of the body
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Email(s) Created!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I would do this at the mail server automatically so it applies to everything. Who is your mail provider?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warn before sending emails to external domains in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757373/warn-before-sending-emails-to-external-domains-in-outlook)